# alias "rm -rf /"="echo 'idiot'" why not work?

Tags: shell, alias

I wondered what if the name of an "alias" includes a command with arguments? I tried:

`alias "rm -rf /"="echo 'idiot'"`

but it does not work; what would be the correct way?

Comment: You'd have to invoke it as `"rm -rf /" whatever` or something similar to get it to work, in which case you definitely deserve the message.  Be wary of protecting yourself with cover functions or aliases for `rm`; one day you'll find yourself without the safety net, and then you make a mistake, and it really hurts.  If you want different behaviour, write and use your own `del` or `delete` or `remove` command (function, alias) which protects you as you see fit.  If you attempt to use it on a machine that is missing your custom code, you'll still be protected (the command won't be found).

Answer (score 7):

You can do it this way:

```
rm() {
  if [ "$1" = "-rf" ] && [ "$2" = "/" ]; then
    echo 'idiot'
  else
    command rm "$@"
  fi
}
```

Of course it doesn't match all cases, but you can modify this script if you want.

Comment: For more background on when to use an `alias` and when to use a `function`, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function

Answer (score 4):

There's no really good way to do that, though there have been attempts to do so.

The name of an alias or function must be a single identifier. `rm -rf /` is parsed as a command `rm` with two arguments, `-rf` and `/`. By the time that's done, it's too late for the shell to distinguish it from any other `rm` command.

On some systems, the default user startup scripts are configured to alias `rm` as `rm -i`, and of course you can do that yourself -- but since the `-f` option overrides `-i`, that doesn't help in this case.

The tcsh shell has a configuration shell variable `$rmstar` that causes it to recognize an `rm` command with the `*` wildcard as an argument; if it's set, the shell prompts the user for confirmation before executing the command. It's useful when you accidentally type `rm * .o` rather than `rm *.o`. But it doesn't catch `rm -rf /` because there's no wildcard. (And it doesn't help if you're not using tcsh.) Note that this can only be done in the shell itself; the `rm` command, or any replacement for it, doesn't see the `*` wildcard, it only sees a list of file names.

You can replace the `rm` command with something that prevents you, or tries to prevent you, from doing dangerous things. But *any* `rm` command is potentially dangerous. You could write an `rm` wrapper script that *always* prompts for confirmation before doing anything, and put it in, say, `$HOME/bin` -- but then you'll quickly develop the habit of dismissing the prompt any time you want to remove something.

You can replace the `rm` command with something that *moves* the specified files and/or directories into a "trash can" of some sort, from which you can easily recover them. But I often need to run `rm -rf some-directory` just to recover disk space. And again, this doesn't help for `rm -rf /`; that would delete the trash can directory as well, and even moving system files can ruin your day.

Solutions that look for specific command-line options are limited. Checking specifically for `rm -rf /` won't catch, `rm -fr /`, or `rm --force --recursive /`, or `rm -rf /etc`, which is nearly as dangerous as `rm -rf /`.

And any tweak that modifies the behavior of the `rm` command applies *only* when that tweak is available. If you manage to make the `rm` command safer in your own environment, you'll come to depend on it, which is likely to make you less careful when you're in another environment (say, on a machine where you haven't fully set up your account, or when you're using a different account for some reason).

The solution is to *cultivate good habits*.

- Back up your data, and make sure you're actually able to recover files from your backups. (I'm not very good about this myself.)
- Use the `root` account as rarely as possible. A non-root user running `rm -rf /` will do far less damage than `root` doing so. (I'm not sure whether a non-root user running `rm -rf /` will do *anything*; I'm not going to test it to find out.) Use `sudo` for individual commands rather than running a shell as `root`.
- Think of `rm` as a *dangerous* command. If you've typed an `rm` command, re-read what you've typed before typing Enter.